# Function argument: vector<Clazz*>& vs vector<Clazz>&

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have two functions which act on objects of type Clazz and the only difference between them is the way I access their members:

```
void foo(vector<Clazz*>& v) {
    ...
    v[0]->method();
    ...
}

void foo(vector<Clazz>& v) {
    ...
    v[0].method();
    ...
}
```

It is not possible/practical to outsource the code which does not use v and write a simple wrapper function. I could simply convert one vector type to the other in a loop and pass the new vector to the one standardised version of the function but i need a fast solution which supports both variants.

Is there a way to merge both functions and still retain the flexibility of both input types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is what a template function is for.

You will have to somehow abstract away "the way [you] access their members". Perhaps via an additional template lambda parameter that provides an abstract means of accessing the members. Or, perhaps, via a helper overload.

```
Clazz &gimme(Clazz &c) { return c; }

Clazz &gimme(Clazz *c) { return *c; }
```

Then, have your template function:

```
template<typename vector_t> void foo(vector_t & v)
```

... call `gimme(v[n])` to access each member in the vector.